# Initialization of a class's struct with vector of structs in constructor's intialization list

Tags: c++, class, struct, constructor, initialization-list

I wonder how could I describe a constructor's initialization list in order to define a class's variable of a struct type containing vector of structs:

```c
class Class {

public:

Class() : _list( {{3, 4}} ) {}
Class(List _l) : _list(_l) {}

struct Value {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct List {
    vector<Value> values;
};

private:
List _list;

}


int main() {
    Class c( {{2, 4}} );
}
```

Let's assume that some kind of a backward compatibility could induce some benefits of such approach.

Since the code with a default constructor only `Class() : _list( {{3, 4}} ) {}` seemed to compile without errors, appending a `Class(List _l : _list(_l)` constructor brings:

`error: expected ')' before '_values'|` and a code with definition of an objects gives back:

`error: no matching function for call to 'Class::Class(<brace-enclosed initializer list>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)'|`.

I've tried few ways to solve it, e.g. few different definitions of an initializing list, different ways of passing of an argument in the constructor or defining constructors of a `struct List`. Part of those seemed to bring the mentioned errors.

Finally, I wonder if such functionality could be possible to achieve in such way.

Thanks for help and advice in advance.

Comment: I wrote an answer. If you found it useful please consider voting/accepting it! [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Just add one more brace-pair and it will be  OK!:

```
Class() : _list( {{{3, 4}}} ) {}
```

And also:

```
Class c( {{{2, 4}}} );
```

Brace-enclosed construction is usually used to indicate brace-enclosed-initialization of the data members **or** construction of elements from a range.

The `Value` struct here can be initialized simply by `{3,4}` because it has 2 data members and no other constructor.
In case of `std::vector` however this type of construction is used to indicate set of elements that are going to be stored in the vector in its construction.
Finally for `List`, the brace-enclosed constructor can only take one data of the type`std::vector<Value>` in order to use it to initialize  the only data member `values`, which itself is of type `std::vector<Value>`.

Here each class needs a brace enclosed initializer. One for `Value`, one for `std::vector<Value>` and one for `List`.
In case of `Value` there could be only 2 data inside the braces (the most inner braces). But for `std::vector<Value>` there can be one or more data of the type `Value` inside its braces. Finally for List there can only be one data inside its braces(the most outer braces).
For example:

```
Class() : _list( {{{3, 4}, {5, 6}}} ) {}
```

Is also OK and results in putting 2 data of the type`Value` inside the vector!

Also in order to use member structs/classes in constructors declare them first:

```
class Class {
public:
    struct Value;
    struct List;
    Class() : _list( {{{3, 4}}} ) {}
    Class(List _l) : _list(_l) {}
    struct Value {
        int a;
        int b;
    };
    struct List {
        std::vector<Value> values;
    };
private:
    List _list;
};
```

In **comparison**, it would be OK to remove the braces for `List` If the class was defined like:

```
class Class {
public:
    struct Value;
    struct List;
    Class() : _list( {3, 4} ) {}
    Class(List _l) : _list(_l) {}
    struct Value {
        int a;
        int b;
    };
    struct List {
        Value values;
    };
private:
    List _list;
};
```

But that is because List (and also Value)  does not have a **user defined constructor** and List only has **one** data member!

Good luck